# Javascript filter, foreach, startsWith on array

Tags: javascript

I  need to be clarified on a little point, I'd like to filter an array only with some starting specific element.

I've tried something like this :

```js
const array = [{
  "name": "NAME",
  "values": ["[John].[15]", "[Lois].[17]"]
}];

const arrayFinal = array.filter(element => element.values.forEach(el => el.startsWith("[John].")));

console.log(arrayFinal);
```

But the printed array is empty. Do I miss something?

Thank you by advance

Comment: `forEach` will always return `undefined` so the filter will treat that as falsy and return nothing

Comment: `forEach` -> `some`. The `forEach` method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in place of `forEach` to return `true` if any of the element starts with `[John].` As VLAZ already commented `forEach` doesn't return anything

```js
const array = [{ name: "NAME", values: ["[John].[15]", "[Lois].[17]"] }];

const arrayFinal = array.filter((element) =>
  element.values.some((el) => el.startsWith("[John]."))
);

console.log(arrayFinal);
```

Comment: Ok great i understand better, but it doesn't apply the filter on the array. I thought it would return the array with only the value of John